CUPS Webinterface Time Format
On my CUPS (UNIX/Linux Printing System) Webinterface, let's say:
http://192.168.0.2:631/jobs/

it shows a printjob currently being processed as follows:
processing since Thu 12 Dec 2024 08:21:13 PM CET

I would really like to have the time in 24h format, without AM/PM.
Does anyone know how to change that, or where CUPS gets its time formatting from?

Is the time correct?  Do you want 24 Hour format system-wide, or just in CUPS?

The system locale is in 24h format. So if I type date in the shell, I get something like Fri 13 Dec 13:27:32 CET 2024

I found it!
CUPS not only takes the language setting of the browser to decide which language to display text in, but also what date/time format to use.
So (in Chrome) when I set the top preferred language to English-US, I get AM/PM time format. When I set the browser to prefer English-International I get 24h time format as desired.

Glad you found that.
